# Ownership of a VIP contact

Tags: contacts

I would like to know the best way in CiviCRM to assign ownership of VIP contact records to specific staff members. When a contact is flagged as part of our VIP group, how can we designate an owner for their record from our staff?

The idea is for certain staff members to be stewards of these important VIP contacts. Their responsibility would be to periodically review the assigned VIP records to verify that the contact details are current and that VIP status remains warranted. Other staff members can however edit the record.

Would a tag showing which staff member owns oversight of that VIP contact be the way to do it. Is there a better way (that doesnt require creating tags of all staff)?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest creating a new relationship type: "VIP Steward" -> "Vip" and you can then add this relationship between staff members and contacts.

Comment: Sounds like a great solution. Many thanks!

Comment: Sorry for not getting back sooner but I have only just had time to implement this. It works great! Great idea. Many thanks.